# How to write custom event that fires when DBGrid.SelectedRows.Count changes?

Tags: delphi

How to write a custom event that fires when DBGrid.SelectedRows.Count changes?

I need this events to conditionally show/hide a panel when the selected rows in a DBGrid are [zero | one] or more than one.

Since now I'm using the following code, but IMO coding a custom event is more appropriate here:

```pascal
TForm3.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: DBGridDrawState);
begin 
  Panel1.Visible := TDBGrid(Sender).SelectedRows.Count > 1; 
end;
```

Comment: You should use the event that occurs when you select rows, like `onclick`.

Comment: I need a generic event that works either with the mouse or the keyboard: OnClick works only with the mouse

Comment: Ah OK. I would then suggest also checking the keydown or keypress event for the component. Looks like @bummi has already included that notion in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch all events changing the internal Bookmarklist yoe will have to override

1. LinkActive
2. KeyDown
3. MouseDown

above example just as interposer class, could be changed to a new component.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,  Grids, DBGrids, DB, ADODB;

type
  TDBGrid=Class(DBGrids.TDBGrid)
  private
    FOnSelectionChanged: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure LinkActive(Value: Boolean); override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer); override;
  published
    published
    property OnSelectionChanged:TNotifyEvent read  FOnSelectionChanged write FOnSelectionChanged;
  End;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADODataSet1: TADODataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure MyOnSelectionChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses unit3;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoDataset1.Active := Not  AdoDataset1.Active;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.OnSelectionChanged := MyOnSelectionChanged;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyOnSelectionChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Caption := IntToStr(TDBGrid(Sender).SelectedRows.Count);

end;

{ TDBGrid }

procedure TDBGrid.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);

begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnSelectionChanged) then FOnSelectionChanged(self);

end;

procedure TDBGrid.LinkActive(Value: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnSelectionChanged) then FOnSelectionChanged(self);

end;

procedure TDBGrid.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnSelectionChanged) then FOnSelectionChanged(self);

end;

end.
```